# What does it mean to create a "Local" branch in git? and how can I create one?

Tags: github

I am new to github and I wanted to know, how can you make a local branch in git? Is the master always a local branch?

Answer (score 0):

A local branch is a branch that exists in your local file system and not (yet) on the git remote server.

Create one via:

```
git checkout -b "whatever branch name you desire"
```